# Turn off error checking in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, syntax-checking

Is there a way to turn off syntax / error checking while writing queries in MySQL Workbench?  It lags almost constantly as I'm typing (presumably to check syntax, as it informs me of errors), and gets even worse if I'm connected to a remote server.

Is there any way to turn this off?  I check Preferences and the available documentation and I can't find anything.

I'm using 6.0 Community Edition on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: I can't find anything specifically related to syntax checking, but there's a code-completion option under `Edit | Preferences |SQL Editor | Productivity` that might help.

Comment: do you not have enough memory on your computer to run MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: 16gb on a quad-core i7, so I don't think so!  Like I mentioned, I'm pretty sure it's doing syntax checking as I type against objects defined in the database, which is why it takes longer for remote DBs (as opposed to localhost)

Comment: @MikeW: Good suggestion, but I already turned that off before posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL Workbench tries to get help information form the server. With a remote server this can block for a moment which is why it has been redesigned to use a background thread or can be entirely switched off (and be run manually, if necessary). Get the [latest MySQL Workbench release](http://mysqlworkbench.org/) for this feature.

Comment: This does not answer the question of "how" completely though. After downloading the latest version, how do you turn it off?

Comment: In fact, my answer is about the context sensitive help, not error checking (even though also this feature had been redesigned to not block the UI). Error checking cannot be switched off at all. So, given that, the only relation to the original question that a new Workbench version also fixed that problem.